# Перенос элементов против часовой стрелки

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться, почему элементы 1 и 2 не переносятся на 2 элемента против часовой стрелки, что нужно подправить? Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include iostream>
#include stdlib.h> 
#include stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int ROW, COL; 
    int **mArray;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Перенос элементов прямоугольной матрицы на 2 элемента против часовой стрелки\n\n";
    cout << "Введите количество столбцов:\n";
    cin >> COL;
    cout << "Введите количество строк: \n";
    cin >> ROW;
    if (COL != ROW)
    {
        mArray = new int *[ROW];

        cout << "Введите элементы матрицы \n";
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            mArray[i] = new int[COL];
            for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) cin >> mArray[i][j];
        }
        int * arrPerimetr = NULL,
            perimetr = 0,
            i = 0, j = 0, n = 0, m = 0, k = 0,

            shift = 2; /*  насколько сдвигаем  */

        perimetr = (ROW + COL) * 2 - 4;
        m = perimetr - 1;
        arrPerimetr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * perimetr);

        for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && j == COL - 1))
                {
                    arrPerimetr[n] = mArray[i][j];
                    n++;
                }
                if (j == 0 && i > 0 || (i == ROW - 1 && j < COL - 1))
                {
                    arrPerimetr[m] = mArray[i][j];
                    m--;
                }
                printf("\t%d", mArray[i][j]);
            }
        }

        puts("\n\n   Результат:");

        /*fill*/
        n = shift;
        k = 0;
        m = perimetr - 1;
        for (i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
        {
            printf("\n");
            for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
            {
                if (i == 0 || (i > 0 && j == COL - 1))
                {
                    mArray[i][j] = arrPerimetr[n];
                    n++;
                }

                if (j == 0 && (i > 0 && i <= shift))
                {
                    mArray[i][j] = arrPerimetr[k];
                    k++;
                }

                if (
                    (j == 0 && i > shift &&  i < COL - 1)
                    ||
                    (i == ROW - 1 && j > 0 && j <= ROW)
                    )
                {
                    mArray[i][j] = arrPerimetr[m];
                    m--;
                }

                printf("\t%d", mArray[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        free(arrPerimetr);
    }
    else cout << "\n\nМатрица квадратная" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

P.S. Вот скриншот работы программы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поместите экранный снимок непосредственно в вопрос (на панели редактора вопроса есть соответствующая кнопка). Сам перенести не могу, так как сайт по ссылке открывается некорректно  даже под анонимайзером.

Comment: Индексы где-то напутал. 4,6 и 5,3 работают же.